# How can I detect that a dom element has been deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm just getting started learning rspec and capybara; I see many examples of testing new content being loaded into a dom, but not so much of verifying that an element has been removed.

I'd like to find an element, click the link to make it disappear, and verify that it is gone.

Something like:

```
item = find(".list-delete")
item.click
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
page.should not_have(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

```
item = find(".list-delete")
item.click
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
item.reload.should be_nil
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I got:     Failure/Error: item.reload.should be_nil
       expected: nil
            got: #<Capybara::Element tag="a">